# How to properly use placeholders in re module?

Tags: python, regex

I had this simple code which uses python re module's placeholder..

```
(?P<name>...)
```

My goal is to get the value(number) just before the "/" character. The value's length can range from 4 and so on...

I have written this code below.

```
import re

s = "hello world 1234/book"
x = r"^h.*(?P<test>[0-9].*)/.*$"

y = re.search(x, s)
print y.group('test')
```

However it just returns:

```
>>> 4
```

My ideal result is:

```
>>> 1234
```

I would really appreciate any hint.

Comment: Try with something like `x = r"^h.*?(?P<test>[0-9].*)/.*$"`. Note the `?` after the first `*`.

Comment: @dcg, wow. that worked.. thanks .

Answer (score 1):

In regex you don't need to worry about what is the starting string unless you want to match it. In your case you don't need to write `.*` before the placeholder you used.

so you can just use the regex like below:

```
s = "hello world 1234/book"
re.search(r'(?P<text>[0-9].*)/.*$', s).group(1)  # '1234'
```

Comment: I'd assume he's using `^h.*` for a reason—his regex is intended to reject anything that doesn't start with an `h`, while yours will accept such strings. (Of course I could be wrong, and maybe he put it there for no reason at all, but I wouldn't start with that assumption.)

Comment: though he didn't mentioned it's use in question

Comment: True, but why would he put the `h` there otherwise? Surely it's not just dumb luck that it happens to match the first character of his search string?

Comment: at beginning one may use all the stuff which is explored and once it worked out we slightly remove at check the effect, even in my beginning of code I have used some unnecessary code but improved it after learning so we can't assume why it is there and we can't write answer on guess basis, but instead what is asked in question by user

Comment: But you answer _is_ guessing. You're guessing that the `h` is there for no reason, and can therefore be discarded without breaking the desired semantics. That might be OK if you explain that you're doing that (and you sort of do), but it needs to be clear that you are changing what his regex does in ways that go beyond making the group match `1234` instead of `4`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the value (number) just before the `"/"` character, you could use your `regex` as this:

```
import re
s = "hello world 1234/book"
y = re.search(r"^h.*?(?P<test>[0-9].*)/.*$", s)
print(y.group('test'))
# 1234
```

Or simply without placeholders:

```
import re
s = "hello world 1234/book"
y = re.search(r"([0-9]+)/.*", s)
print(y.group(1))
# 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your problem has nothing at all to do with placeholders or named groups; you're doing that part just fine. To verify that, try capturing every piece as an unnamed group and printing out what you get:

```
>>> s = "hello world 1234/book"
>>> x = r"(^h.*)([0-9].*)(/.*$)"
>>> y = re.search(x, s)
>>> print(y.groups())
('hello world 123', '4', '/book')
```

See? You're getting the exact same `'4'` for the group you care about.

Printing out all the groups is usually a helpful test of what's going on. For an even better test, use one of the many online regex debuggers, which can highlight the matches and explain them to you. For example, [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0bL8Iy/2/) shows (via coloring) that the `^h.*` is matching `hello world 123` even without changing your regex to make it more debuggable.

Anyway, the problem with your existing regex is that the first `.*` will match as much as possible while allowing the rest of the pattern to work—which means it'll match `'hello world 123'`, as you can see above, instead of just `'hello world '`, as you want.

If you want to toggle the greediness of a pattern, put a `?` on the end:

```
>>> s = "hello world 1234/book"
>>> x = r"(^h.*?)([0-9].*)(/.*$)"
>>> y = re.search(x, s)
>>> print(y.groups())
('hello world ', '1234', '/book')
```

And now you can remove the groups you don't want and restore the name to the one you do want.